# Query for differences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- table1: id, created
- table2: id, modi

```
+------------+----------+
|    id      | created  |
+------------+----------+
|    1       | 18/01/01 |
|    2       | 18/01/01 |
|    3       | 18/01/01 |
|    4       | 18/01/01 |
+------------+----------+
```

```
+------------+----------+
|    id      | modi     |
+------------+----------+
|    1       | 18/01/02 |
|    4       | 18/01/02 |
|    1       | 18/01/03 |
|    2       | 18/01/03 |
|    3       | 18/01/04 |
|    2       | 18/01/04 |
|    2       | 18/01/05 |
+------------+----------+
```

I need a query (MySQL) that prints out how many days takes every user to modify the log, grouped by days. For example, 1 day - 3 users, 2 day - 7 users, etc...

```
+------------+----------+
|    days    | num_id   |
+------------+----------+
|    1       | 2        |
|    2       | 1        |
|    3       | 1        |
+------------+----------+
```

I managed to do this:

```
select datediff(table1.id, table2.modi) as date_diff, count(*) as nums
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id
group by date_diff
```

The problem is that it is also including the second entry (or more) besides the first one, but I would only want the first one to be included.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question; that would really help here.

Comment: Please share some sample data.

Comment: If you have a simple table schema of the 2 tables as well as expected output, that would make it a lot easier to help you. As of right now, we basically have take a guess and hope that we hit the mark. And no one likes guessing when it comes to answers.

Comment: If you want to measure it by user, then shouldn't there be something like a userId in both tables?  Or are those `id` columns the userid's instead of the primary keys of those tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added data, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use proper column for `datediff` fucntion

```
select datediff(table3.modi,table1.created) as date_diff, count(*) as nums
    from table1 left  join 
    (
    select id,min(modi) as modi  from table2 group by id
    ) 
    as table3
    on table1.id = table3.id
    group by date_diff
```

Comment: It also includes in the count the second entry of one id.

Comment: @JesusSono which one

Comment: For all the IDs that have more than one entry, the sum of the query's result need to be the same number as the ID's sum.

Comment: dont sure what you want but  it seems to me you need this query   select sum(datediff(t2.modi,t1.created)) as date_diff, t1.id as nums_id
from t1  join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by  t1.id  could you please check and reply me t1=table1 and t2=table2

Comment: @JesusSono https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e8cff6e73d1140168d2935ffbcd51fd check this link for demo

Comment: Finally, I found the solution, Check this, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bcc7c2220d6401e5586a1b08fbdf9b66

Comment: @JesusSono thanks but you dont need extra sub-query i just changed your query and updated in answer  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78a386d4cd24d4cb897dd0689476600b

Answer (score 0):

just add a Join Left in the query. :)

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer?